# Automatically Open Drawer / sidebar menu on Initialization

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie on Android Studio (Java)
My question is, how if user open my App for the first time, drawer open automatically. Currently if drawer are trigger when user swipe the sidebar.

Below are code for opening the drawer

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activityMain = this;

    if (!imgloader.isInited()) Tools.initImageLoader(this);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);

    prepareAds();
    initToolbar();
    initDrawerMenu();
    prepareImageLoader();
    cat = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.id_category);

    // first drawer view
    onItemSelected(R.id.nav_all, getString(R.string.title_nav_all));

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivitySearch.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // for system bar in lollipop
    Tools.systemBarLolipop(this);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);` after initializing your drawer.

Comment: I just put code drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); before function onItemSelected ?

Comment: @Koyix you should put it wherever you want the drawer to open

Comment: in onCreate() / onResume() and check a flag in shared prefs if its the first app start...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for start drawer on Activity start:

```
DrawerLayout drawer;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //for starting drawer from left.
    }

}
```